# How to prevent Go back to protected page after logout

Tags: security, symfony

I use login and logout in Symfony2 and firewals and access_control in my `security.yml` look like this:

```
firewalls:
  secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /%locale%/

access_control:
    - { path: ^/.*/translator, roles: ROLE_TRANSLATOR }
    - { path: ^/.*/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My problem is that when I do logout, everything works fine and I'm redirected to unauthorized page but when I press Go Back in browser I'm back in authorized page and I'm authorized again and I can browse all authorized pages.

How to prevent this? Let say how to manage to be redirected to login page after Go Back button?